# Segmentation fault overloading << operator

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

I overloaded operator << for my dynamic array Tvector container and i want to cout areas of squares.

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, TVector &s) {
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i){
        os << "[" << s[i].Area() << " ";
    }
    os << "]";
    return os;
}
```

Function area

```
double Square::Area() {
    double len_a = a.dist(b);
    double len_b = b.dist(c);
    return len_a * len_b;
}
```

If i just

```
cout << a.Area();
```

everything works fine.
But if i want to cout dynamic array, compilator throws segmentation fault error.
main function fragment

```
    Square a;
    std::cin >> a;
    Square a1;
    std::cin >> a1;
    TVector v;
    v.push_back(a);
    v.push_back(a1);
    std::cout << v;
```

[image: Segmentation fault]

P.S Code for TVector

```
TVector::TVector()
    : _array(nullptr)
    , _size(0)
{

int TVector::length() {
    return _size;
}

Square &TVector::operator[](int idx) {
    return _array[idx];
}

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, TVector &s) {
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i){
        os << "[" << s[i].Area() << " ";
    }
    os << "]";
    return os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, TVector& s) {
    Square a;
    is >> a;
    s.push_back(a);
    return is;
}

TVector::~TVector()
{
    clear();
}
```

Comment: And what is `TVector`?

Comment: Your code snippets most likely don't contain the source of the bug. Please read how to make a [mre].

Comment: @Evg added TVector code on pastebin

Comment: loaded TVector functions which is needed to solve this problem, i think

Comment: The `TVector` class doesn't seem to honor the Rule of Three, so I'm guessing the `Square` class doesn't either.  If you're also doing nasty C-like dynamic memory stuff in that class, there's a reasonable chance that copy-assignment is causing this issue.  Or, if `Square` is a non-trivial type, there could be problems with `malloc` because you're not doing any placement-new/delete management.  There's also the issue that `realloc` can move the memory so if that will break anything inside `Square` weird things can happen.  You should use array-new/delete at the very least.

Comment: @paddy but why when i `cout << Square.Area()` it doesn't throw segmentation fault?

Comment: Why are you assuming that's even related to the issue?

Comment: Undefined behavior means anything can happen. It doesn't mean the code has to crash.

Comment: Can you just give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Temporarily comment out the `clear();` if this fixes the problem the bug is likely the rule of 3 violation. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)